# Oracle Application Express - 'ORA-01843: not a valid month error' in one table only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am creating a database in Oracle Application Express and am having a problem inserting a date into one of the tables.

```
INSERT INTO VIEWING( VIEWING_ID, VIEWING_DATE, TIME, PROPERTY_ID, AGENT_ID)
VALUES('3', '12-07-2015' ,'10:00','1', '101');
```

I've tried every combination of date format, and trying to force the date to my correct format

```
to_date('12-07-2015','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

But nothing is working

```
CREATE TABLE Viewing (
        Viewing_ID   number(10) NOT NULL, 
        Viewing_Date date NOT NULL, 
        Time         timestamp(7) NOT NULL, 
        Property_ID  number(10) NOT NULL, 
        Agent_ID     number(10) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (Viewing_ID));

ALTER TABLE Viewing ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Viewing_Agent_ID FOREIGN KEY (Agent_ID) REFERENCES Agent (Agent_ID);
ALTER TABLE Viewing ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Viewing_Property_ID FOREIGN KEY (Property_ID) REFERENCES Property (Property_ID);
```

Every Resource I have found suggests it is most likely a parsing or syntax error but so far nothing has helped.

I have a second table in the schema that I can insert dates into without a problem, the only difference on this table is that the date is required (I have tried making it nullable to test and I still get the same error)

I should point out that Im am completely new to Oracle and this is part of a study project. If I had I choice I would be using SQL Server! But Ive been at this for hours and think its time to admit defeat!

Thanks

Comment: what is the date format in the database? what is returned when you do `select sysdate from dual`?

Comment: Hey, 12/10/2015 is returned, sorry I should have mentioned that!

Comment: BTW, `timestamp` and `date` both hold date **and** time. The difference being `date` is whole second precision, and `timestamp` supports fractional second precision. Unless `time` is for some time besides the viewing time, would probably be best to replace `viewing_date` with `viewing_datetime timestamp(7)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a better Idea, Ill change it over

Answer (score 4):

It is due to `TIME` column, not `VIEWING_DATE`. This worked:

```
INSERT INTO VIEWING( VIEWING_ID, VIEWING_DATE, TIME, PROPERTY_ID, AGENT_ID)
  VALUES(4, date '2015-12-07' , timestamp '2015-12-07 10:00:00',1, 101);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I cant believe I didn't realise this earlier. You just saved my computer. Another 5 minutes and it was going out the window!

Comment: Also, `to_timestamp('10:00', 'HH24:Mi')` if you only want to specify time. The date portion will default to current date.